# Is it possible to run selenium (Firefox) web driver without a GUI?

Tags: ubuntu, selenium, webdriver

We are considering upgrading our production server from Ubuntu-**desktop** 10.04 to Ubuntu-**server** 12.04.

We have various services running on our current desktop OS such as Selenium Web Driver. My question is can the Selenium Web Driver be run from a cli-based system?

My immediate thought is that it can't, because it relies on Firefox, but I'd like for someone to prove me wrong!

Comment: related: [Running Headless Selenium with Chrome](http://www.chrisle.me/2013/08/running-headless-selenium-with-chrome/)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [headless-browser](/questions/tagged/headless-browser).

Yes, it's possible to run Selenium on Firefox headlessly. Here is a [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20161220172036/http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/) you can follow.

Here is the summary steps to set up Xvfb

```
#install Xvfb
sudo apt-get install xvfb

#set display number to :99
Xvfb :99 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:99    

#you are now having an X display by Xvfb
```

Comment: This works and supports screenshots.  I use this.  It also works with google chrome.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore (at least not easily, because it requires a new geckodriver much like chrome did)

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano This still works. The directions are for creating a virtual display using `Xvfb`, not for installing and configuring Selenium (which requires having `geckodriver` on the path).

Comment: I like doing this from within Python, which you can do with `subprocess.Popen('Xvfb...')` or `os.system('Xvfb...')`, but make sure to do it before importing the webdriver.

Comment: I don't understand why we need Xvfb if we are using `headless-browser`

Comment: `xvfb-run` - run specified X client or command in a virtual X server environment

Answer (score 40):

Chrome now has a headless mode:

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
```

Comment: PhantomJS is currently not in active development. Git repository is archived.

Comment: Selenium also stopped supporting PhantomJS with the following message "UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been depreciated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead"

Comment: Python 3.8: `'headless'` didn't work, but `'--headless'` did, however.

Comment: Last I checked, `--headless` works with even `FirefoxOptions()`

Comment: Is it possible to run webdriver without headless mode?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. You can use `HTMLUnitDriver` instead for `FirefoxDriver` while starting webdriver. This is headless browser setup. Details can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver).

Comment: Would this support functions such as save_screenshot()?
http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/python-selenium-webdriver-capture.html

Comment: Haven't tried, but it may be possible because you're effectively still creating a UI, but showing it on a 'virtual' window.

Comment: HTMLUnitDriver will NOT support capture screenshot as content is not rendered at all (Issue 1361). An alternative I can think of is to use getHTMLSource and show the HTML page rather than screenshot.

Answer (score 10):

If you want headless browser support then there is another approach you might adopt.

https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver

It was announced during Selenium Conference and it is still in development. It uses PhantomJS as the browser and is much better than HTMLUnitDriver, there are no screenshots yet, but as it is still in active development.

Answer (score 8):

An optional is to use `pyvirtualdisplay` like this:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=[800, 600])
display.start()

#do selenium job here

display.close()
```

A shorter version is:

```
with Display() as display:
    # selenium job here
```

This is generally a python encapsulate of `xvfb`, and more convinient somehow.

By the way, although `PhantomJS` is a headless browser and no window will be open if you use it, it seems that `PhantomJS` still *needs* a gui environment to work.

I got Error Code -6 when I use `PhantomJS()` instead of `Firefox()` in headless mode (putty-connected console). However everything is ok in desktop environment.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: You do not need XVFB to run headless Firefox anymore. Firefox v55+ on Linux and Firefox v56+ on Windows/Mac now supports headless execution.

I added some how-to-use documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode#Selenium_in_Java

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173662/discussion-on-answer-by-nicholas-dipiazza-is-it-possible-to-run-selenium-firefo).

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm not sure, but I think XVFB is still required.

Comment: I've been using headless browsers on Firefox and Chrome for several years now. The WebDriver interface for Selenium even supports a setHeadless parameter now.

Answer (score 4):

Install & run containerized Firefox:

```
docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox
docker run --rm -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size=2g selenium/standalone-firefox
```

Connect using `webdriver.Remote`:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is GhostDriver which is now officially supported by WebDriver: [Ghostdriver actual performance gain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194371/ghostdriver-actual-performance-gain/14707494#14707494)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that HtmlUnitDriver webclient is single-threaded and Ghostdriver is only at 40% of the functionalities to be a WebDriver.

Nonetheless, Ghostdriver run properly for tests and I have problems to connect it to the WebDriver hub.

Comment: Does this provide any new information that the other answers do not?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to set your window-size dimension.  just like：

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080');

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path = './chromedriver')
```

if also not working, try increase window-size dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run test scripts without a browser, But you should run them in headless mode.