# How to save a web page as a picture with python?

Tags: python, html

I want to save a web page as a picture with python but I don't know how to do.

Is there any package (or open-source software) could help me ?

Comment: here're [several code examples to get the screenshot of a web page (calling chrome as external command, driving headless chrome using selenium, driving firefox using marionette, and pyppeteer for chrome (text in Russian, code in Python)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/821319/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *(or inspect the code from)* [`pywebshot`](http://www.coderholic.com/pywebshot-generate-website-thumbnails-using-python/), an open source tool that seems to do exactly what you need.

```
$ ./pywebshot.py -t 500x250 http://stackoverflow.com http://meta.stackoverflow.com
Loading http://stackoverflow.com... saved as stackoverflow.com.png
Loading http://meta.stackoverflow.com... saved as meta.stackoverflow.com.png
```

Comment: note: `pywebshot` requires [`python-gtkmozembed`](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/gtk-embedding.html) package

Comment: Very true, it's all in the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

You could use selenium webdriver to get a screenshot in different browsers e.g., in Chrome:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

url, filename = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', '/tmp/stackoverflow.com.png'

browser = Chrome()
try:
    browser.get(url)
    browser.get_screenshot_as_file(filename)
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

[`xvfb` allows to run selenium headlessly (without GUI)](http://www.chrisle.me/2013/08/running-headless-selenium-with-chrome/) if you want to take many screenshots in parallel. See also [Is it possible to run selenium (Firefox) web driver without a GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10399557/4279).

Note: there is a bug [chrome driver 2 makes screenshot just of visible part of page](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294). See workarounds there.