# python write text in web without opening any browser

Tags: python, browser, mechanize, hidden

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " onload="window.parent.tinymce.get('page_text').fire('load');" contenteditable="true"><p>Works</p><p>&nbsp;</p><pre class="lang-py prettyprint prettyprinted"><code><span class="kwd"><br></span></code></pre></body>``
```

I need to type text here `<p>Works</p>` instead of "Works" some other text.But I dont want to open browser to do it via Selenium or other stuff.Can I do it hidden?
whole page  [Click here](https://note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/102ecca33aceb7b7d8971e9b9f232470?page=1)

Comment: Your description of the problem is rather poor and does not give any context. Please enhance it, so that we can get an idea what you are asking for.

Comment: I think (s)he wants to edit page's HTML so that the text is added to the notebook. See the `whole page` url

Comment: Ruben,yes thats waht  I want

Comment: You'll have to use `selenium` for that, since mechanize won't be able to make the JavaScript calls the website does. You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) along with selenium, if you want the browser to run in the background (just putting it in simple terms).

Comment: maybe you can play with their API instead of wanting to change the HTML, check requests the website do when you type.
Look, when you save, here's what is sent:
`{"number":1,"title":"Work fine","text":"<p>testtttt</p>\n<p>testtttt</p>\n<p>testt</p>","format":"html","pad_key":"102ecca33aceb7b7d8971e9b9f232470"}`

Comment: [These](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568899/does-selenium-support-headless-browser-testing) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399557/is-it-possible-to-run-selenium-firefox-web-driver-headless) about headless selenium may help.

Comment: Jason Estibeiro, thanks its help